# Xcode. How to add SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER to .xcframework

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode

I have two sdk frameworks (via files), but

> 'Field' has different definitions in different modules;
> first difference is definition in module 'SDK.Swift' found property

Accroding to answers about this ploblem - setting **SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER=NO** in main target did not help in my case.

May be I can add **SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER** to them separately somehow?